# Comparing a JsonArray with a Enumeration

Tags: json, scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, enumeration

I(scala beginner) was searching, but i couldn't find a fitting way to solve this following problem.

The Enumeration object(never changes):

```
object EyeColorEnum extends Enumeration{
  val Blue = Value("blue")
  val Brown = Value("brown")
  val Gray = Value("gray")
  val Green = Value("green")
}
```

The Json Array(case1):

```
"eyeColor": ["blue", "gray", "green"]
```

The Json Array(case2):

```
"eyeColor": []
```

The Json Array(case3):

```
"eyeColor": ["orange", "pink", "green"]
```

This solution should be a json validation for the field "eyeColor".

Case1 and case 2 are valid.

Case 3 is invalid.

```
for (i <- 1 to(jsonArray.value.length - 1)) {     
  for (j <- 1 to(jsonArray.value.length - 1)) {
    if(jsonArray(i).as[String] == enumArray(j).toString) {
      // Item from A exists in B
      true
    } else {
      // Item from A does not exist in B
      checker = checker + 1
    }
  }
}
```

These `for` are not working how i want them to work.
Is there probably a way more easy way to get this job done?

Thank u very much.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why that is not working is that for comprehensions used in this way are doing .foreach calls against the Range instance you've created in the parens (which returns Unit rather than the value you're attempting to return):

```
(1 to (jsonArray.value.length - 1)).foreach{i => ...}
```

It sounds like you want a combination of the forall and exists methods that collections in Scala provide.

Comment: Did u mean something like this?
(0 to (jsonArray.value.length - 1)).foreach{i =>
        (0 to (enumArray.length - 1)).foreach{j =>
          if (
            jsonArray(i).as[String] == enumArray(j).toString) {
            found +=1
          }
        }

Comment: That's something like what it's turning the code into, but the implementation you almost certainly want shouldn't use foreach but forall and/or exists.

Comment: This is the best solution:
(for (needle <- needles if !haystack.contains(needle)) yield needle).isEmpty

Answer (score 0):

Is there somebody who could point out how to avoid the `var`?

This is my ugly solution:

```
def apply(enum: Enumeration, jsonArray: JsArray): Boolean = {
    val enumArray  = enum.values.toArray
    var found = 0
    jsonArray.value.length  match {
      case 0 => true
      case _ =>
        (0 to (jsonArray.value.length - 1)).foreach{i =>
          (0 to (enumArray.length - 1)).foreach{j =>
            if (jsonArray(i).as[String] == enumArray(j).toString) {
              found +=1
            }
          }
        }
      found == jsonArray.value.length
    }
  }
```